# Upload artifacts to artifactory with python

Tags: python, python-requests, artifactory

I am trying to upload artifacts to an artfactory repo with requests, but I am getting 405 errors.  I have a working bash script that achieves this goal, but I really need a python implementation.

**python**

```
import os
import hashlib
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

username = 'me'
password = 'secrets'


target_file = '/home/me/app-1.0.0-snapshot.el6.noarch.rpm'

artifactory_url = 'https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory'

def get_md5(fin):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(fin, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(8192), ''):
            md5.update(chunk)
    return md5.hexdigest()

def get_sha1(fin):
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(fin, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(8192), ''):
            sha1.update(chunk)
    return sha1.hexdigest()


def upload(fin):
    base_file_name = os.path.basename(fin)
    md5hash = get_md5(fin)
    sha1hash = get_sha1(fin)
    headers = {"X-Checksum-Md5": md5hash, "X-Checksum-Sha1": sha1hash}
    r = requests.post("{0}/{1}/{2}".format(artifactory_url, "yum-local", base_file_name),auth=(username,password), headers=headers, verify=False, data=open(fin, 'rb'))
    return r
```

**bash**

```
art_url="https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory"
user="user"
pass="password"


function upload {
    local_file_path=$1
    target_folder=$2
    if [ ! -f "$local_file_path" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: local file $local_file_path does not exists!"
    exit 1
    fi

    which md5sum || exit $?
    which sha1sum || exit $?

    md5Value="`md5sum "$local_file_path"`"
    md5Value="${md5Value:0:32}"
    sha1Value="`sha1sum "$local_file_path"`"
    sha1Value="${sha1Value:0:40}"
    fileName="`basename "$local_file_path"`"

    echo $md5Value $sha1Value $local_file_path

    echo "INFO: Uploading $local_file_path to $target_folder/$fileName"
    curl -i  -k -X PUT -u $user:$pass \
    -H "X-Checksum-Md5: $md5Value" \
    -H "X-Checksum-Sha1: $sha1Value" \
    -T "$local_file_path" \
    ${art_url}/"$target_folder/$fileName"
           }

upload "/projects/app.war" "libs-release-local/com/company/app/app-comp/1.0.0/"
```

Comment: This is a life savior simply as a good example of using Python to publish to Artifactory!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error 405 stands for using wrong HTTP method.
According to [the documentation](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact), artifact deployment should be done using PUT.

That means that you can't use `requests.post`, but need to use `requests.put` instead.

Answer (score 7):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that your bash script is using a `PUT` while your python script is using `POST`.

The only other potential problem I see is the way you're constructing the URLs is radically different.

In the bash script the URL you create ends up being

```
https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/company/app/app-comp/1.0.0//app.war
```

In the python script you're using

```
https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/yum-local/app-1.0.0-snapshot.el6.noarch.rpm
```

Also, it's important to note that `yum-local` is hard-coded into every URL you generate.

---

That aside, your `get_md5` and `get_sha1` functions could be more simply written because file objects are iterable, e.g.,

```
with open(fin, 'rb') as f:
    for chunk in f:
        md5.update(chunk)
```

Comment: that will actually read in lines at a time, rather than fixed block sizes. This will probably not be noticable most of the time, but could result in either very large "chunks" being loaded, or lots of very small ones.

Answer (score -1):

Your iterators will not stop in python3 since they compare with '' for sentinel, it should be b''